# ¿Hay una adoración general del acento castellano por hispanohablantes como hay una adoración del acento inglés por los angloparlantes?

Tags: españa, historia, cultura-de-masas

Es un hecho de conocimiento general que el acento de Inglaterra se considera muy fino por los angloparlantes de otros países. Me he dado cuenta de unas correlaciones:

- el idioma inglés se llama por los ingleses
- con ellos se originó el idioma y por ellos se difundió a través del mundo
- durante los años del imperialismo ellos establecieron los estándares léxicos y de pronunciación
- por mucho tiempo los habitantes de las colonias británicas y los ingleses hablaban con el mismo acento porque constaban de la misma gente

Todas estas observaciones también se aplican con respecto a los españoles en América Latina.

Por eso me pregunto, ¿hay una adoración general del acento castellano por hispanohablantes como hay una adoración del acento inglés por los angloparlantes?

Comment: En mi experiencia, no. En Hispanoamérica oí decir que nuestro acentos de España les suena muy "duro" y seco.

Comment: @fedorqui También he escuchado eso, pero no he hablado de este tema con muchas personas de varias regiones. Gracias por compartir :)

Comment: Recuerdo que cuando éramos niños y de vez en cuando daban en la TV algún dibujo animado con doblaje peninsular en vez de latino/neutro, el acuerdo con mi hermano era que no eran lo mismo los _monitos españoles_.

Comment: @Rafael  ¿«*Monitos*»!  ¡Qué **terrible**!

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I agree it sounds weird. It happens frequently with slang. Compare with _toons_. _Dibujos animados_ (motion/"animated" pictures) is better, but _monitos animados_ or simply _monitos_ used to be kid slang in my country at the time, (and probably still is, not sure.)

Comment: @Rafael Oh my gosh, I think I misunderstood. I thought that they were using the Iberian voiceover actor to imply that, because of their accent, Spaniards were monkeys, like a different species. Perhaps I've been exposed to American racism too long (especially with the Charlottesville KKK-nazi revival this week).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La respuesta corta es **no**, pero me va a ser difícil fundamentarla.

No puedo encontrar ningún estudio formal de cómo es percibido el castellano peninsular en Hispanoamérica, pero, como ya se ha dicho en comentarios, en general se lo percibe como muy diferente. En realidad *es* muy diferente, incluso comparado con las grandes diferencias que existen entre los dialectos americanos.

- A nivel fonético, no existe ningún dialecto americano del español que oponga /s/ y /θ/ (el sonido de la *zeta* y la *ce* ante *e/i* en el registro estándar de España). Tampoco es tan común (aunque sí existe) la pronunciación apical de /s/ que es habitual en España. Estos dos sonidos son bastante frecuentes.
- A nivel gramatical, ningún dialecto americano utiliza el pronombre *vosotros* ni sus posesivos ni las formas de segunda persona del plural que lo acompañan, como es regla en España; esto también marca mucho al hablante europeo.

Estas diferencias podrían resultar estéticamente neutras o positivas, pero en mi experiencia se ven generalmente como negativas. Paradójicamente, la valoración estética a veces es opuesta a la moral: muchos hispanoamericanos odian cómo suena el español europeo pero a la vez afirman que en su país "se habla mal" o "se trata al idioma a las patadas" o "el español latinoamericano es más pobre que el europeo". En una discusión online hace un par de años [la BBC recopiló opiniones](http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2015/10/151019_hay_festival_debate_que_pais_habla_mejor_espanol_yv) sobre esto. Parece ser que los chilenos son los menos felices con su dialecto (una persona dice que esto es así porque Chile es "el último país al que llegaron los españoles", como si estar apartado de España implicase menor sofisticación en el idioma) mientras los paraguayos están felices de la cantidad de palabras indígenas que han incorporado a su dialecto (la mayor parte de los paraguayos son bilingües en español y guaraní, y bastante adeptos al *[code switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)*, según mi limitada experiencia).

Comment: Es verdad. Es difícil fundamentar ese "no" pero es un hecho que así es. A cada uno nos gusta nuestro acento y se nos dificulta un poquito el de las otras regiones, especialmente si no tienes amigos de ahí. Cuando tienes algún amigo, por ejemplo argentino, te acostumbras y hasta te empieza a gustar el acentico. :-)

Comment: @DGaleano lo del acento argentino es bastante interesante.  Para muchos amigos, o es el acento más sexi del mundo hispanohablante o el acento más horroroso del mundo jaja.  Yo creo que hasta cierto punto lo que ha dicho pablod76 casi se puede decir de todos los acentos bien conocidos (mejicano, cubano, rioplatense, peninsular, etc).

Answer (score 6):

A modo de apreciación personal, como chileno, te puedo decir que **no nos gusta** el acento español. Nos parece "duro" y cansador.

Sin embargo (y esto es lo importante), es un acento **muy prestigioso**.

Un ejemplo: el locutor del principal noticiero de la cadena de televisión estatal chilena, Amaro Gómez-Pablos, es Español. Ha vivido varias décadas en Chile y no ha relajado un milímetro las zetas, que son, es sabido, la causa de su credibilidad imbatible. A cualquiera que le preguntes te dirá que odia el acento de Amaro, pero ahí está, leyendo las noticias todas las noches.

Es contradictorio, cierto. Pero creo que esto tiene más que ver con la curiosa psicología social de Chile que con una tendencia americana general.

Si eres español y quieres conquistar chicas, ganar elecciones o estafar, empaca tu acento y vente a Chile.

Comment: Buscando datos para mi respuesta observo que dentro de los memes sobre el propio dialecto los más frecuentes son los de los chilenos. ¿Está bien mi impresión?

Comment: @pablodf76 Parece ser cierto, aunque tenemos en todo un doble estándar. Criticamos nuestra forma de hablar pero al mismo tiempo estamos seguros de que somos los que mejor hablamos en el mundo. Es un mito urbano que el dialecto chileno es el preferido para los doblajes porque es el más neutro y correcto de todos.

Comment: A propósito de este tema, los jugadores chilenos de fútbol que se van a otro país hispanohablante, normalmente a España o Argentina, aunque sea por dos meses, vuelven con el acento extranjero y no lo sueltan hasta la tumba.

Comment: En Barcelona siempre decían que les era imposible entender a Alexis Sánchez. Al parecer tiene un acento muy cerrado.

Comment: El acento de Amaro Gómez-Pablos es inventado, en un programa españoles no lo reconocían como perteneciente a ningún acento de España. ¿Gallego? ¿Catalán? ¿Madrileño? No. Le hace un flaco favor a los esp. porque es considerado ridículo. Por qué sería prestigioso? Prestigioso con el sentido de buena fama? En la actualidad no hay mucha difusión y le choca a la gente cuando dicen cosas como "me apetece". Prestigioso en el sentido de correcto, eso ya no es el acento sino la forma de hablar,y lo dudo, prestigioso para la hipercorrectitud del profesor banderas tal vez o para gobiernos de antaño.

Answer (score 6):

Esta es una opinión tambien. La pregunta sobre si los latinoamericanos adoramos el acento español, como los americanos los Británicos: NO. Pero es algo que fue cambiando con el tiempo.
Yo soy un poco mayor, y siempre recuerdo que si nos topábamos en la TV con una peli o show con acento de España, casi siempre alguien decía "nooo, cambiá eso!" (soy argentina).
Hasta hace unos años atrás con el auge de Game of Thrones, a veces veía videos que colgaban en Youtube (no tenía HBO), y alguna vez le compartí a amigos y flia links de algun video de esta serie con doblaje español de España. Y me decían, "no. Prefiero verlo en inglés aunque no entienda". (y me molestaba a mi, cómo soportar a la Madre de Dragones, la que no arde, reina de Meeren... etc, etc hablando así?). Puede ser la costumbre al latino neutro o al original Inglés, pero por un buen tiempo, algo en este acento era inmirable.
Peeero.... series que muchos argentinos adoran desembarcaron con Netflix, como Elite o La Casa de Papel y creo que las cosas cambiaron. El mundo está mas cerca y acentos distintos, si alguna vez molestaban, ahora ya cada vez menos. Ya empezamos a aceptar esa conglomeración de zetas  :)
Creo que las nuevas generaciones van a dejar de ver acentos lindos o feos, solo los veran diferentes. De hecho ya es así.

Comment: Cierto. Es muy difícil generalizar en este tema, porque sobre una situación muy dispar de reacciones a las características del habla de otras regiones, se actualizan fenómenos como la influencia del productos culturales (Netflix), series entrañables como las de Gomez Bolaño (El Chavo del 8, querido en toda Latinoamérica), y el impacto moderno de "influencers" (youtubers famosos) que modifican y sazonan el gusto con la variedad universo acústica de modismos y cantos distintos en generaciones nuevas

Answer (score 4):

Por lo general, los españoles no aguantan los acentos latinos, y los latinos no aguantan el acento castellano. Es un rechazo mutuo.

Fuente: entra en cualquier video/película de cualquier sitio de internet que ofrezca o doblaje castellano o latino, y lee los comentarios. Sugiero cualquier video de Los Simpson, de openings de series, de traileres de películas, o de canciones de Disney. El que sea, da igual.

Comment: La respuesta mejoraría considerablemente si ofreciera fuentes que la sustenten. De lo contrario, es más un comentario que otra cosa. Por favor dale a [edit] e incorpora más detalles, tal y como se sugiere en [answer].

Comment: Eh, el caso de los doblajes es algo muy peculiar.  Hay que entender que las traducciones se realizan de forma *muy* diferente.  La versión latinoamericana tiene que escribirse con un castellano neutralizado en cuanto a país porque es la que se usa en todos los países latinoamericanos y hay poca jerga común.  La versión peninsular puede adaptarse mucho más al habla cotidiana precisamente porque se la ve en solo un país (bueno, probablemente en G.E. también así que en dos).  Entonces la principal diferencia muchas veces no es el acento, sino la traducción en sí, que puede ser *muy* diferente.

Comment: @guifa - Creí que en España hay por lo menos otros dos idiomas (catalán y euskera), por lo que imaginaba que eso da una gran variación de expresión.  Perdón, me siento muy ignorante en cuanto a España.

Comment: @guifa ¿Qué es G.E.?

Comment: @Rodrigo Guinea Ecuatorial

Comment: Este tema de los doblajes es interesante. El ejemplo de los Simpson es perfecto. Hacen un doblaje para hispanoamérica (aprox 420 Millones de personas) y luego tienen que repetirlo para los 46 millones de españoles porque ellos no se aguantan el acento de este lado del océano. :-)

Comment: Creo que el argumento de los doblajes y comentarios al respecto en Internet no es suficiente para sostener que existe un rechazo mutuo entre acentos. No nos gustan otros doblajes porque estamos acostumbrados a un doblaje en concreto. Además, incluso aunque no haya cambio de acento, lo rechazamos. El doblador original de Homer en los Simpsons para España murió, y nunca me he acostumbrado al nuevo. Me gusta tan poco como oirlo con acento hispanoamericano. Pero eso no significa que rechace esos acentos. Al revés, me gustan y creo que aportan una riqueza inestimable al idioma.

Answer (score 4):

Soy argentino, para mí el español ibérico, español europeo o el español peninsular, es el más hermoso. Las distinciones entre "Z" y "S", como llegan a pronunciar la "Ll" Aquí en Argentina te confirmo que hay un afecto a la variante ibérica, en el sentido de algunas palabras, queda como tipo 'posh' (que tienen de concepto a los británicos en Estados Unidos o en el propio Reino Unido a los ingleses.)

Tenemos un gustito a la variante ibérica, abunda esos 'hispanofilos', me imagino que más de un latino se enamoraría del acento de Madrid.

Pero no voy negar que a nuestros oídos, escuchar el acento "europeo" choca algunas veces, porque en Hispanoamérica no llegó a predominar varios factores de España (a diferencia de Guinea Ecuatorial, Sahara Occidental).

1. **La distinción de S /s/ con Ce-Ci; Z /θ/** (como en "Th"ing). El origen es que en Andalucía y en las Islas Canarias seseaban, y los colonizadores eran de esas regiones. Luego con la independencia quedamos con el seseo. Yo, personalmente me gusta distinguirlas y **siempre uso eso cuando hablo con gente de otra lengua que quiere aprender español.**
2. **El uso de Vosotros** El español hablado en las colonias no usaba el "Vosotros" usaba siempre el "Ustedes", porque el ustedes es el "Vosotros" (Y'all) extremadamente formal. Sólo los españoles y las autoridades tenía el *Vosotros* mientras que los mestizos, nativos, africanos, etc. Usaban el "ustedes" para dirigirse a ellos, es el trato social. Y posteriormente pasó ese "Ustedes" como el típico pronombre de la segunda persona en plural, abarcando en todo. Entre nativos, africanos, mestizos se "ustedeaban". De ahí tienen ejemplos de como en los territorios de América y las Islas Canarias no usan Vosotros. **También uso ese querido pronombre** Es semejante a mi querido "VOS" de ahí viene el origen
   *Vos comés/Vosotros coméis; Vos dijistes/Vos dijistéis; Vos vengás/Vosotros vengáis*
3. **Arcaísmos** En España usaban algunas palabras, que actualmente solo lo habla cierta parte de la población en las zonas rurales, o la gente más vieja como *pararse* (ponerse de pie), *anteojos* (gafas), *platicar* (conversar), *prieto* (oscuro), *esculcar* (buscar en el sentido de registrar o husmear), *recibirse* (graduarse), *alcancía* (hucha, de uso común en zonas de Andalucía), *alberca* o *pileta* (piscina), *estacionar* (aparcar). En Hispanoamérica aún se conserva.

Lo mismo son los estadounidenses con el Inglés Británico, conocí estadounidenses que no entienden la variante británica. Y la diferencia que abunda es mayor.

*Color vs Colour*; *Airplane vs Aeroplane*; *Encyclopedia vs Encyclopaedia*; *Practice vs Practise*; *Diarrhea vs Diarrhoea*; *Center vs Centre* y en pronunciación como *Brother; Laboratory; Advertisement; Controversy; Hurricane; Route; Brochure; Inquiry; Four, etc.*

Answer (score 2):

En México, hablar como si fueras español se toma como un chiste:

> ¡Coño Manolo, que la *volvishte* a cagar!

En mi opinión personal, el acento "español" (si es que tal cosa existe) me parece otro acento más, dado por los regionalismos. En cada país tienen sus acentos característicos y unos son mas entendibles que otros.

En cuanto al español "latinoamericano" que se habla en Ciudad de México, Lima o Bogotá, tengo entendido que lo heredamos casi al 100% del que se hablaba anteriormente en España, y que fueron los propios españoles los que con el tiempo lo cambiaron, hasta donde sé, por la forma de hablar de un rey de España que no podía pronunciar bien la S.
Lo de que usan mucho el pasado perfecto creo que es por su cercanía con Francia e Italia.

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.se Aunque esta contribución es interesante, no estoy seguro de que conteste a la pregunta (Hay algún tipo de acento preferido entre hispanoparlantes?). Aportas cierta perspectiva de lo que ocurre en México, aunque no aportas referencias para validarla y enseguida pasas a la opinión personal. No es que no sea válida, pero en este stack solemos preferir respuestas que se apoyan en hechos un poco más objetivos. Visita [tour], [answer] y [help] para familiarizarte un poco más con la filosofía de los stacks.

Comment: Lo del rey de España que no podía pronunciar la "s" me lo tienes que contar. Y que todos los españoles cambiaron su acento por esa razón... también. ??

Answer (score 1):

Yo, aunque carezca de fuentes para demostrar un punto, quisiera dar mi opinión al respecto.

Cómo alguien que lleva poco tiempo viviendo en España, desde Uruguay, puedo afirmar que, al menos desde el lado de Latinoamérica, está todo muy polarizado. Por un lado, están quienes adoran el acento español, ya que es bastante característico de la zona, mientras que el otro odia al mismo, lo toma como broma y utiliza la palabra "gallego" de manera despectiva, como una forma de referirse a cualquier español.
Acá, por otro lado, he visto gente a la que le gusta mi acento y el de mi familia en general, pero también hay algunos que se quedan viendo cuando vamos de compras. Es cuestión de cada uno.
Algo tan personal como son los gustos particulares son muy complicados de generalizar, pues cada persona es un mundo y, en consecuencia, piensa distinto.

Answer (score 0):

Lo del rey es una tontería que se han inventado en EE.UU. y tonto es quien se lo crea (solo hay que buscar en Google para ver que es un bulo). Hace falta ser tonto para pensar que hace varios siglos un rey vino con un defecto fonético a España y todo el mundo lo imitó, cuando no había ni radio ni televisión ni internet. En cuanto he leído lo de "la volvisthe a cagar", me ha vuelto a molestar. Cuando bromeando, y de malas, nos intentan imitar, no pueden. No tienen ni idea. Lo hacen mal, por ejemplo ese "volvishte". Nosotros no decimos sh ahí. Pronunciamos una "s" perfecta. Pronunciamos una "s", "z" y "c" perfectas (al menos los del norte). En el sur de España y en otros países hablan distinto, pero no tolero que critiquen el acento original y menos quienes no son capaces de hablar distinguiendo entre rosa y roza y encima, debido a eso, tengan tantas faltas ortográficas y escriban "s" en lugar de "c" o "z" o viceversa y se dediquen a criticar el acento del norte de España. Yo no critico, pero si me critican... y yo sí tengo razones para hacerlo ;). Y sí, en España también hablamos cometiendo defectos gramaticales (laísmo, leísmo, loísmo, quesuísmo, dequeísmo, etc.) pero, en general, hablamos mil veces mejor que la media de los iberoamericanos. El otro día discutí con iberoamericano que me decía que el fonema "v" existe y se puso arrogante, no tuve más remedio que corregirlo y decirle que no tenía idea, que el fonema "v" en español no existe (en español de ningún lado) y quien lo pronuncia es un pretencioso que no se da cuenta de que la ignorancia es atrevida. En cuanto a si gusta o no un acento, será como todo, para gustos colores.